# como validar el formato de un email con php

Tags: php, javascript

hola tengo un formulario de contacto y he logrado validar que los campos fueron llenados, pero no se como hacer que el email tenga el formato correcto y sino tire error, como puedo verificar que contenga @ el contenido en ese campo, o como se hace esa validacion?
Paso lo que tengo:

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact_form">
                <form action="confFormulario3.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">
                    <input type="text" id="nombre" class="boton" name="nombre" placeholder="Cómo te llamas">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="boton"  placeholder="En qué podemos ayudarte?"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="buttonEnviar" class="boton" value="ENVIAR">
                </form>
            </div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
/*Capturamos las variables del POST con operadores ternarios*/
$email=   ( empty($_POST["email"])   )  ?  NULL : $_POST["email"];
$name=    ( empty($_POST["nombre"])    )  ?  NULL : $_POST["nombre"];
$message= ( empty($_POST["mensaje"]) )  ?  NULL : $_POST["mensaje"];
/*Verificamos que los tres datos fueron posteados*/
if ($email && $name && $message){
   $para = 'timondigitalweb@gmail.com';
   $asunto = "mensaje de la web de el punto!!!!!!!!!!!!";
   $mailheader = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Reaply-To:".$email."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

   $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$name."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Email: ".$email."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Mensaje: ".nl2br($message)."\n";

   mail($para, $asunto, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("error al enviar mensaje, intente nuevamente");
   echo "<script>
            alert('Gracias por tu contacto! en breves nos estaremos comunicando 1');

        </script>";


}else{
    //Aquí puedes también redirigir con un mensaje de error
    echo "<script>alert('Controla la informacion ingresada, el mensaje NO se ha enviado');</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Puedes empezar validando en el cliente. Desde HTML5 se puede usar algo como [`<input type="email" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/email). Y del lado del servidor, puedes validar con [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.examples.validation.php). Podrías usar un ternario: `$isValid= (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? TRUE: FALSE;` Y evaluar `$isValid`. Las otras dudas, casi mejor que las plantees aparte, ya que este sitio funciona por preguntas y son cosas distintas.

Comment: ok, edité la pregunta y cree una diferente para la redirección

Comment: @A.Cedano ya incorpore el `type="email"` pero no entiendo del todo en que parte del PHP deberia colocar el ternario?? Me orientas un poco mas sobre esto por favor que es muy básico lo que entiendo de php

Comment: Rectifico parte de mi comentario anterior: no necesitas un ternario para el email, dado que `filter_var` devuelve el dato validado o `false`, puedes capturar el  email directamente en la variable `$email` y dejar la evaluación posterior de las variables como la tenías originalmente (ver respuesta editada).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema que describes hay dos formas de hacerlo.

**Primera opción:**

Para este caso lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es cambiar el atributo del input donde se digita el email de esta forma `type="text"` por `type="email"`.

```
<input type="email" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">
```

**Segunda opción**

Usar el plugin Jquery Validation con el cual valides el formulario y además de ello puedas mostrar tus propios mensajes de error.

Aquí te dejo el código de como quedaría tu formulario aplicando el plugin Jquery Validation

1° Tener el formulario HTML

```
<div id="contact_form">
  <form action="confFormulario3.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">
    <input type="text" id="nombre" class="boton" name="nombre" placeholder="Cómo te llamas">
    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="boton"  placeholder="En qué podemos ayudarte?"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="buttonEnviar" class="boton" value="ENVIAR">
  </form>
</div>
```

2° Crear un archivo Javascript donde se realiza las validaciones correspondientes, al cual llamaré `validacion.js`

```
$(function(){
  $('#form1').validate({
    //En rules defines los campos que quieres validar, con el nombre de los id de cada input
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        nombre: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3
        }
      },
      //En messages describes el mensaje que quieres el usuario visualice por cada cada validación que aplicaste en rules
      messages: {
        email: {
          required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
          email: "El email no tiene el formato correcto"
        },
        nombre: {
          required: "Este campo es obligatorio",
          minlength: "El nombre debe tener al menos 3 caracteres"
        }
      }
}
});
```

**NOTA:** Para que esto funcione, no olvides incluir la libreria del plugin y hacer la llamada del `validacion.js` dentro del archivo donde se encuentra tu formulario HTML, caso contrario no funcionará. Te recomiendo leer la documentación de su página oficial ya que el ejemplo que te muestro es algo básico de las muchas cosas que puedes hacer.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: cuando decis "incluir la libreria del plugin" a que te referis? como la incluyo. Tengo la libreria de JQUERY, no se si es lo mismo??

Comment: @Fernanda Jquery y Jquery Validate no son lo mismo pero el plugin depende de Jquery para que realice su trabajo, si ya tienes Jquery vas por buen camino. Ahora lo que necesitas hacer es descargar la librería la cual se encuentra en el link que puse en mi respuesta, ya en la página te diriges a la pestaña Home donde veras de primera un vídeo de como incluir el plugin y mas abajo el enlace de descarga.

Comment: ok, en un rato lo pruebo y te cuento como me fue. gracias por tu interes

Comment: funciono perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: Genial, que bueno que te haya sido de utilidad.

Answer (score 6):

En este tipo de casos conviene hacer una doble validación: del lado del cliente y del lado del servidor.

### Del lado del cliente

[Desde HTML5 existe el tipo `email` para los elementos `input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/email), con que pongas esto:

```
 <input type="email" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">
```

Te validará el email del lado del cliente.

### Del lado del servidor

Puedes usar [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.examples.validation.php) para validar el email.

Dado que `filter_var` devuelve los datos validados o `FALSE`, puedes por tanto capturar el email así directamente:

```
$email =  filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Y luego el `if` quedaría como lo tienes originalmente en el código:

```
if ($email && $name && $message){
    // ... código
} else {
    // ... código
}
```

Comment: hice las modificaciones que me propones, y ahora valida el mail correctamente pero siempre me indica que hay un error que debo verificar los datos....

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje sale exactamente @Fernanda, este: *`error al enviar mensaje, intente nuevamente`*   o este *`Controla la informacion ingresada, el mensaje NO se ha enviado`*?

Comment: controla la informacion ingresada, el mensaje NO se ah enviado

Comment: @Fernanda, parece que cometiste algún error asignando las variables, compara tu código con mi respuesta como está ahora. Si quieres depura las variables con `var_dump($email);` y `var_dump($name);` y `var_dump($message);`  para ver en cuál(es) de ellas tienes el problema. Y verifica que el `if` quedó de este modo: `if ($email && $name && $message){`

Comment: el error lo habia tenido en cambiar el $mail = ...  por el original que yo tenia y no por el de tu respuesta. Mil gracias funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto te pueda servir para hacer las validaciones que necesitas y también para insertar en tu base de datos:

HTML (contacto.html)

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" id="form-contacto">
  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" onkeypress="return alfabetico(event);">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Mail">
  <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

JS (validaciones.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#enviar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#form-contacto").submit();
    });

    $("#form-contacto").validate({
        rules: {
            nombre: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                emailExt: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            nombre: "Ingrese Nombre",
            email: {
                required: "Ingrese Email",
                email: "Ingrese un Email válido"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#enviar').attr("disabled", true);
            enviarForm();
        }   
    });
});

function enviarForm(){
    var parametros = {
        nombre: $('#nombre').val(),
        email: $('#email').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        data:  parametros,
        url:  'procesar.php', /* Aqui mandas a tu archivo php para insertar los datos */
        type:  'post',
        async: false,
        success:  function (response) {
            /* Puedes elegir entre mostrar un alert o llevarlo a una paginas estatica des respuesta*/
            alert ("Tus datos se enviaron de forma exitosa!");
        },
        error : showError
    });
}

function showError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Ha ocurrido un error procesando la información");
}

/* Validador alfabetico */
function alfabetico(e){
    kc=e.keyCode?e.keyCode:e.which;
    if(kc<32) return true;
    kc=String.fromCharCode(kc);
    if(/[^a-zA-ZüÜáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]/.test(kc)) return false;
}
/* Validador de Correo */
jQuery.validator.addMethod("emailExt", function(value, element, param) {
    return value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.%\+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/);
},'Ingrese un Email válido');
```

En tu archivo php solo basta con que tomes los datos y los insertes dentro de tu base de datos el resto (validaciones) déjalo al archivo JS.
Espero te sirva !