# Como validar un email en PHP antes de enviarlo

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, email

Buen dia

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un tipo de registro de newsletter, esto es que tengo un form con un input y un boton, al dar click en el boton, el email debe ser verificado para corroborar que si es un email y en caso de ser positiva la verificacion entonces lo guarde en una base de datos.

Podrian ayudarme a saber como hacer dicha validacion o verificacion con PHP.

De antemano gracias.

Saludos.

Estaba tratando de hacerlo asi pero no me funciona

Codigo:

```
<?php  


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

if(empty($_POST['correo'])){

    $correo_error = "Se requiere correo electronico";
}else{


    $mail = test_input($_POST['correo']);

    if(filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

        $server = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $database = 'bd_newsletter';

     $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

         if (!$conn) {
         die("Error de Conexion: " . mysqli_connect_error());
          }

        $mail = $_POST['correo'];

         $sql = "INSERT INTO mails_newsletter (correo_usuario) VALUES ('$mail')";
         if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            header("location:newsletter_finn.php");
            }else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);

    }

}


  function test_input($mail){

  $mail=trim($mail);
  $mail=stripslashes($mail);
  $mail=htmlspecialchars($mail);
  return $mail;


  }


  }







 ?>
```

Comment: Tienes esa misma pregunta respondida aqui:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/246610/como-validar-el-formato-de-un-email-con-php Salu2

Answer (score -1):

Puede que mis conocimientos de PHP no sean los adecuados para resolver tu problema pero por si acaso te sirve de ayuda te comento lo que pienso. El FILTER_VALIDATE parece que lo usas bien pero me mosquea la función test_input. Hazte un eco de $mail nada más crearlo y asignarle valor, a ver qué tiene.
Un saludo.